# Laravel faker inside controller unknown format for mobileNumber

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm using PHP Faker in my Laravel project, I need to use Faker in a seeder file rather than a factory file, I'm migrating it over from a factory file, and I'm getting an error thrown:

> Unknown format "mobileNumber"

This works fine in a factory, but why not my seeder file?

What am I missing?

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Application;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Hashids\Hashids;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class ApplicationsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    private $applicants = [];

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 51; $i++) {
            $hashids = new Hashids('', 7);
            $bank = $faker->bankAccountNumber('', '', 8);
            $sort = rand(111111, 999999);

            $hashable = $bank . '' . $sort;
            $hashable = trim($hashable);

            // email formatting
            $email = $faker->safeEmail ?? null;
            $email = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $email));

            // postcode formatting
            $postcode = $faker->postcode ?? null;
            $postcode = trim(strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', $postcode)));

            // mobile formatting
            $mobile = $faker->mobileNumber ?? null;
            $mobile = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $mobile));

            $application = [
              'ApiKey' => Str::random(35),
              'AffId' => "aff2020",
              'Application' => [
                'AppFirstName' => $faker->firstName,
                'AppLastName' => $faker->lastName,
                'AppEmail' => $email,
                'BankSortcode' => $sort,
                'BankAccount' => $bank,
                'AppMobilePhone' => $mobile
              ]
            ];

            $applicants[] = [
                'hash' => $hashids->encode($hashable),
                'product_type' => 'payday_form_honeycomb_faker',
                'email' => $email,
                'birthday' => Carbon::now()->subYears(rand(20, 50))->subMonths(1, 12)->subDays(1, 25)->toDateString(),
                'postcode' => $postcode,
                'mobile' => $mobile,
                'data' => json_encode($application),
                'verified_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
            ];
        }

        foreach ($applicants as $applicant) {
            Applicant::insert($applicant);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `phoneNumber` instead, e.g. `$faker->phoneNumber;`

Comment: What are the available types?